# Problem Disabling Back Button in Browser using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i am trying to disable the back button in a Browser, (specifically Microsoft Bing), and it works, but only if i click first in the Window. If i dont click anything first, the back button works, but i dont understand why. Here is my code in js. If I don't click anywhere, and press the button directly, if I can go back, which is what I don't want.:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    history.pushState({ noBack: true }, null, location.href);
});

window.addEventListener("popstate", function () {
    history.pushState({ noBack: true }, null, location.href);
}); here
```

I tried other codes that do the same thing, but none works completely.

In summary, this would be the situation:

1. If I click anywhere in the window first, the code works, making it so that I can't go back with the button.
2. If I don't click anywhere, and press the button directly, I can go back, which is what I don't want.

Here is a picture of the button so here is no confusion:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJOFc.png)

I would like to know why clicking on anything blocks the arrow, but if I don't do anything, it works if I directly click on the arrow, returning me to the previous page. Is it due to the nature of the web browser or am I misusing some event?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable going back in the page by simply using a `<a href="example" target="blank">Example link</a>` and when the user clicks the link, it will redict him in a new window.

**HTML:**`<a href="example" target="blank">Example link</a>`

**JS and JQuery**: `window.open("example")`

How to do it in one window (reopen the window as blank):

```
window.open(location.href); window.close();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The button I was referring to was the arrow that web browsers have to go back one page. The problem is that I didn't create that button, it's already implemented in the browser, so I don't see how I could modify it to do what you suggest.
Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: What it does it creates a window as about:blank in a new tab. And the window.close() will close the other window. How the about:blank tab is opened in a new tabb and it dosen't have history so the browser automaicly disables it. Is that what you wan't? Maybe I miss understand something